# Can't post screenshot, game not recognized Xbox app Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Forza Horizon 4 on Windows 10 Redstone 5. The error when I try to shae a screen capture is *"Sorry, this capture can't be shared. We don't recognize this game."*:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/KiFJgXY]

I can post screenshot of Sea of Thieves so the feature works but i don't know why it doesn't work for this game. I couldn't find solutions on this.

Answer (score 1):

That feature only works for games that were purchased from Windows Store or are compatible with XBox.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/games_windows_10/xbox-app-for-windows-says-battlefield-4-is-not-a/954f7f7f-d134-44a1-835b-a5cc495d30b0 Different game, same issue. You would have found this out just by googling the error message.

Comment: Um, Forza Horizon 4 is an [Xbox Play Anywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Xbox_Play_Anywhere_games) game released for PC through the Windows Store.

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez Most likely the game wasn't purchased ;)